# Will Retina.js Work Properly in iPhone UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, css, uiwebview, retina-display

Building a small iPhone app in XCode and I'm trying to implement a couple images inside a UIWebView. I know the JS library [Retina.js](http://retinajs.com/) works flawlessly in most browsers but I'm not sure how it would handle in a Web View?

It's possible to just use the CSS3 media queries to handle this instead, but that's a lot of extra code. Would love to hear if anybody has experience with this.

Comment: I imagine it would, I dont see why not the iPhone should pick up on the @2x with the Retina.js.

"If your app points to an external HTML page that is optimized for mobile and you desire the images on that page to display retina images when viewed on a retina display mobile device. Here is an awesome resource to help you achieve this."